# Why is required keyword init mandatory inside a generic Array where clause?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, extension-methods

In this subscript code:

```
extension Array where Element: Foo {
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        get {
            return self.first(where: { $0.key == key })
        }
        set {
            self.append(Element(key: key, value: newValue))
        }
    }
}

class Foo {
    var key: String
    var value: Any?

    // Why "required"?
    required init(key: String, value: Any?) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Why is `required` in front of Foo.init mandatory?

If I remove it, I get this error:

`Constructing an object of class type 'Array<Element>.Element' (aka 'Element') with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `required` keyword means that inheriting classes must provide an implementation of the method.

And `extension Array where Element: Foo` means that extension should work for all classes inheriting from `Foo`, so all of them `required` to implement `init(key: String, value: Any?)`.

Therefore `required` keyword must be added to ensure this.

If it was `extension Array where Element == Foo` you wouldn't need to have `required`, because for type `Foo` there's defined `init` with proper signature, and there's no need to have any checks.

Making `Foo` final (`final class Foo {}`) will remove need in `required` too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark the initializer `required` because you are using it from a generic extension which applies to all types inheriting from `Foo` (including `Foo` itself). However, if you didn't mark the initializer as `required`, your `Foo` subclasses might not inherit that initializer in case they defined at least one designated initializer as explained in [Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID222).

So unless you marked the `init(key: String, value: Any?)` initializer of `Foo` `required`, your generic Array extension couldn't guarantee that the initializer method called in the extension exists for all types the extension applies to.

If you only want to apply the extension to the `Foo` class and don't want to apply it to its subclasses, you can use `extension Array where Element == Foo {...` and in this case you won't need to mark the initializer as required, since the `Foo` type is guaranteed to have that initializer.